# elementary primitive of $1/\cos(x^2)$

Tags: integration

I have to calculate $$\int \frac{1}{\cos(x^2)} dx $$
My guess is that there is no "elementary" primitive but i want to proof it.

My idea is to rewrite the function in term of $e^{x^2}$ that has no elementary primitive for Liouville theorem.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(differential_algebra)

Comment: ok but i need the last step ...